How to get radio th:field value in back-end (binding Thymeleaf)
<input type="radio" th:field="*{questoes[__${iter.index}__].respostaCorreta}"
       th:value="${alternativa.texto}">

I'm working on a project using Thymeleaf and Spring Boot. In my form, I have a set of radio buttons generated dynamically using Thymeleaf. Each radio button is associated with a text input field, and I'm using th:field and th:value attributes to bind the input values. However, when I submit the form, the th:field for the radio button (respostaCorreta) sends both the old value and the new th:value, resulting in something like "OldResponse,NewResponse". I want to send only the new value (th:value) and ignore the old one. How can I achieve this?
System.out.println("\\n\\n\\n" + questaoDTO.getRespostaCorreta() + "\\n\\n\\n");

The result is TH:FIELD,TH:VALUE, but I want just TH:VALUE.
I want to send only the new value (th:value) and ignore the old one. How can I achieve this?
Front-end:
<form th:object="${quiz}" id="quizForm" th:action="${quiz.id == null} ? '/quiz' : '/quiz/' + ${quiz.id}"
    method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="quizTitle" th:field="*{titulo}" placeholder="Título do Quiz"
            required>
        <label for="quizTitle">Título</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="totalPontos" th:field="*{totalPontos}"
            placeholder="Pontuação" value="0" readonly required>
        <label for="totalPontos">Pontuação</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="file" id="imagem" th:field="*{imagem.arquivo}">
        <label for="imagem">Selecione uma foto para este quiz</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating mb-3" id="teste">
        <select class="form-select" id="category" th:field="*{categoria}" required>
            <option th:each="categoria : ${categorias}" th:value="${categoria.id}" th:text="${categoria.nome}">
            </option>
        </select>
        <label for="category">Categoria</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-floating mb-3" id="inputQuestao">
        <!-- Questões serão adicionadas aqui -->
        <fieldset th:each="questao, questaoStat : ${quiz.questoes}">

            <legend class="text-center">Pergunta [[${questaoStat.index} + 1]]</legend>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{questoes[__${questaoStat.index}__].texto}"
                    placeholder="Texto da Pergunta" required>
                <label th:for="*{questoes[__${questaoStat.index}__].texto}">Pergunta</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                    th:field="*{questoes[__${questaoStat.index}__].respostaCorreta}" placeholder="Texto da Pergunta"
                    readonly>
                <label th:for="*{questoes[__${questaoStat.index}__].respostaCorreta}">Resposta Correta</label>
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-3 gap-3">
                <div class="col form-floating">
                    <input onfocusout="alterarPontos()" type="number" class="form-control"
                        th:field="*{questoes[__${questaoStat.index}__].pontos}" placeholder="Pontos" required>
                    <label th:for="*{questoes[__${questaoStat.index}__].pontos}">Pontos</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col form-floating">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control"
                        th:field="*{questoes[__${questaoStat.index}__].imagem.arquivo}">
                    <label th:for="*{questoes[__${questaoStat.index}__].imagem.arquivo}">Selecione uma imagem para
                        ilustrar a pergunta</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h5>Alternativas</h5>
            <div th:each="alternativa, alternativaStat : ${questao.alternativas}" class="mb-3">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center gap-3">
                    <div class="form-floating flex-grow-1">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                            th:field="*{questoes[__${questaoStat.index}__].alternativas[__${alternativaStat.index}__].texto}"
                            placeholder="Digite a possível resposta" required>
                        <label
                            th:for="*{questoes[__${questaoStat.index}__].alternativas[__${alternativaStat.index}__].texto}"
                            th:text="${{'A)', 'B)', 'C)', 'D)'}[__${alternativaStat.index}__]}"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="radio" 
                            th:field="*{questoes[__${questaoStat.index}__].respostaCorreta}"
                            th:value="${alternativa.texto}"
                            th:id="'alternativa_' + ${questaoStat.index} + '_' + ${alternativaStat.index}" />
                        <label th:for="*{questoes[__${questaoStat.index}__].respostaCorreta}"
                            th:text="Correta"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </fieldset>

    </div>

    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnNovaQuestao">Adicionar Nova Pergunta</button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Salvar Quiz</button>
    </div>

</form>

Backend:
@PostMapping("/quiz/{id}")

@Transactional
public String alterarQuiz(@ModelAttribute QuizDTO dto) {
    Quiz existingQuiz = quizRepository.findById(dto.getId()).orElseThrow();

    existingQuiz.setCategoria(dto.getCategoria());
    existingQuiz.setTitulo(dto.getTitulo());
    existingQuiz.setTotalPontos(dto.getTotalPontos());

    ImagemQuiz imagemQuiz = existingQuiz.getImagem();
    if (imagemQuiz == null) {
        imagemQuiz = new ImagemQuiz();
        imagemQuiz.setQuiz(existingQuiz);
    }
    imagemQuiz.setNomeArquivo(dto.getImagem().getArquivo().getOriginalFilename());

    try {
        imagemQuiz.setArquivo(dto.getImagem().getArquivo().getBytes());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Tratar IOException aqui
    }

    existingQuiz.setImagem(imagemQuiz);

    // Limpar e adicionar questões
    existingQuiz.getQuestoes().clear();
    for (QuestaoDTO questaoDTO : dto.getQuestoes()) {
        Questao questaoEntity = new Questao();
        questaoEntity.setTexto(questaoDTO.getTexto());
        questaoEntity.setPontos(questaoDTO.getPontos());

        System.out.println("\n\n\n" + questaoDTO.getRespostaCorreta() + "\n\n\n");
        questaoEntity.setRespostaCorreta(questaoDTO.getRespostaCorreta());

        // IMAGEM DA QUESTÃO BANCO DE DADOS
        ImagemQuestao imagemEntity = new ImagemQuestao();
        imagemEntity.setNomeArquivo(questaoDTO.getImagem().getArquivo().getOriginalFilename());

        try {
            imagemEntity.setArquivo(questaoDTO.getImagem().getArquivo().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Tratar IOException aqui
        }

        questaoEntity.setImagem(imagemEntity);

        // ALTERNATIVAS DA QUESTÃO BANCO DE DADOS
        List<Alternativa> alternativasEntity = new ArrayList<>();
        for (AlternativaDTO alternativaDTO : questaoDTO.getAlternativas()) {
            Alternativa alternativaEntity = new Alternativa();
            alternativaEntity.setTexto(alternativaDTO.getTexto());
            alternativaEntity.setQuestao(questaoEntity);
            alternativasEntity.add(alternativaEntity);
        }

        questaoEntity.setAlternativas(alternativasEntity);
        questaoEntity.setQuiz(existingQuiz);
        existingQuiz.getQuestoes().add(questaoEntity);
    }

    quizRepository.save(existingQuiz);
    return "redirect:/backoffice/quiz";
}


You shouldn't be binding two inputs to the same th:field... th:field="*{questoes[__${iter.index}__].respostaCorreta}".
